# $\liminf$ and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $f$ is continuous, is it true that $\liminf_{t \rightarrow 0}f(t) = \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(1/n)$? This is of course true when I instead have $\lim$ instead of $\liminf$, but I'm not sure what happens when I have a $\liminf$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. Valid is the following:
$$
\liminf_{x\to 0}f(x)=\liminf_{|y|\to\infty}f\Big(\frac{1}{y}\Big)=\liminf_{y\to\pm\infty}f\Big(\frac{1}{y}\Big).
$$
Because if $x\to 0$, then IT IS NOT TRUE THAT $\frac{1}{x}\to\infty$, but what is true is
 $\frac{1}{|x|}\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

If $f$ is continuous, then $\lim\limits_{t \to 0} f(t)$ exists and is equal to $\liminf\limits_{t \to 0} f(t)$.

As you stated, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(\frac{1}{n})$ exists, and when a limit exists it is equal to the $\liminf$.

In conclusion: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim$ exists then $\liminf$ exists and $\liminf=\lim$. An in this case $\lim$ exists because...

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If $f$ is continuous at $t=0$, then $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}f(t) = f(0)$ and also $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(1/n) = f(0)$. But if $\lim$ exists it is equal to the $\liminf$. Therefore, $\liminf_{t\rightarrow 0}f(t) = \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}f(1/n)$ (=$f(0)$). You only need continuity at $t=0$.